# how to integrate google login without firebase in bare Expo App

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I want to implement Google login in my ejected expo App as per [doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/) it requires `google-services.json` file from firebase which I don't have. I already implement whole backend logic on my server so i just need **successful token** after login.
I also check [expo-google-auth](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/) but after installation, it giving me an error that **emulator not found**(lib issue).

so how can I implement google login without Firebase.

Comment: maybe i'm late but if you are interested there are some links [1](https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#google) [2](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/)